# check radio button on a form based on value retrieved from database

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate the "gender" value stored in database (jsonObj.TEMP.RECS[x].GENDER) onto the HTML form.  Let say if the value is "Male", I want the radio button for "Male" to be selected. Please help.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("gender").value = jsonObj.TEMP.RECS[x].GENDER;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `querySelector` since `getElementsByName()` will return array of objects and you want to check the one with specific `value` in `jsonObj.TEMP.RECS[x].GENDER`, check example bellow :

```
document.querySelector('input[value="'+jsonObj.TEMP.RECS[x].GENDER+'"]').checked = true;
```

Hope this helps.